# How to append add php conditions while replacing html text in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, jquery-append

basically , when document is ready , I would like to replace the td content with this html content that has some php conditions in it as shown below , but it's not working

```
<?php
 echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
 echo "$(document).ready(function(){";
 ?>
 $('#redeem_freebie).html('<a class="btn" <? if (!$freebies->expired) {?>onclick="applyFreebieNow('<?=addslashes($dialog_copy)?>','<?=addslashes($freebies->get_started_link)?>','<?=$freebies->promo_code_id?>');"<? } ?> style="<?=$freebies->expired ? 'cursor: default;':''?>">Redeem Freebie &gt;&gt;</a>');
<?php 
 echo "});";    
 echo "</script>";
 echo "}";

?>
```

Comment: The real question is why the heck would you echo a piece of jQuery to replace part of the HTML when you can just replace the HTML directly in PHP ?

Comment: All PHP output is processed before sending it to the user.

Comment: @adeneo Possible that the above is being loaded into an already loaded page.

Comment: @Madbreaks - That's not really possible, it's PHP

Comment: I have to include javascript in PHP

Comment: @adeneo Of course it's possible. AJAX.

Comment: It would still be processed by PHP, and javascript would generally be removed when using ajax.

Comment: @adeneo I don't know WHAT you're talking about, but you can absolutely load dynamic HTML (and JavaScript) via Ajax from a PHP server.  It's web programming 101.

Comment: @Madbreaks - you're not getting it, the `html` method replaces the content immediately when the document is ready, but it's completely useless here, as one could just place the condition directly in PHP and replace the HTML without using any javascript at all. I'm aware that ajax can fetch content from the server BTW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#redeem_freebie').html('<a class="btn" <?php if (!$freebies->expired) {?>onclick="applyFreebieNow('<?php echo addslashes($dialog_copy); ?>','<?php echo addslashes($freebies->get_started_link)?>','<?php echo $freebies->promo_code_id?>');"<?php } ?> style="<?php echo $freebies->expired ? 'cursor: default;':''?>">Redeem Freebie &gt;&gt;</a>');
 });   
 </script>
```

Some hint : dont use `<?=` really not clear and your error was here `<? } ?>` <- php short tag

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use some php function when document is ready, you can call an other php page using ajax.

example in jQuery :

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'yourpagewithfunction.php',
        type: "POST",
        data : {variable : value}
    }).done(function(msg) {
            alert(msg);
});
```